# Изменение цвета static control

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно изменить цвет static control по ходу работы программы? Я хочу менять цвет статика с помощью ползунка. Проблема в том что заливает полностью все статики, и с помощью регулятора цвет не меняется.

```
 void Regulator::Cls_OnHScroll(HWND hWnd, HWND hwndCtl, UINT code, int pos)
{
    colorRed = SendMessage(Red, TBM_GETPOS, NULL, NULL);
    colorGreen = SendMessage(Green, TBM_GETPOS, NULL, NULL);
    colorBlue = SendMessage(Blue, TBM_GETPOS, NULL, NULL);
    changeColor(hWnd);
}

HBRUSH Regulator::Cls_OnCtlColor(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc, HWND hwndChild, int type)
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)Static;
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue));
    static HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = NULL;
    if (hbrBkgnd == NULL)
    {
        hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue));
    }
    return hbrBkgnd;
}

void Regulator::changeColor(HWND hWnd)
{
    wsprintf(caption, TEXT("Красный: %d    Зеленый: %d    Синий: %d"), colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue);
    SetWindowText(hWnd, caption);
    SendMessage(Static, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, LPARAM(RGB(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue)));// этот способ не работает
}
```

Comment: Простите, невнимательно прочитал ваш вопрос, я изменил ответ.

Comment: Не вижу, где вы вызываете InvalidateRect. Думаю его нужно вызывать в методе changeColor.

Comment: @zenden2k, добавил InvalidateRect но ничего не изменилось. И мне интересно куда возвращается кисть?
Результат моего кода: http://i008.radikal.ru/1509/f2/ffacfdd29677.jpg

Comment: `PBM_SETBKCOLOR` уберите

Comment: Чтобы изменялся только один статик, проверяйте hwndChild в onctlstatic и если это не тот статик, который вам нужен, либо вызывайте defwindowproc, либо возвращайте из функции `return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE));`

Comment: `HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)Static;` вы приводите HWND к HDC??? Уберите. У вас и так уже есть параметр функции `HDC hdc,`

Comment: @zenden2k, сделал все что Вы написали. Уже заливаем черным только статик который мне нужен, но потом все равно не меняется. В отладчике посмотрел, в if (Static == hwndChild) заходит почему-то только при запуске программы, дальше не хочет.

Comment: Lightness значит вы не вызываете InvalidateRect, либо вызываете, но не для того окна.

Comment: @zenden2k, я просто ей неправильные параметры передал. Все работает так как и хотелось. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обработчике сообщения [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx):

1. Чтобы менять цвет текста, нужно вызывать SetTextColor
2. Чтобы менять цвет фона, нужно возвращать кисть (brush) нужного цвета.

Чтобы контрол перерисовался и менял цвет, надо вызывать [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx) для контрола в OnHScroll.

Comment: По-моему, вы случайно одно слово.

Comment: @Vlad я добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста